# How can I handle this Array object? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

first I have a `NSDictionary`. I do a `NSURLRequest` and load the dictionary with the JSON information from the request.

```
NSDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
                                                    options:kNilOptions 
                                                      error:&error];
```

This Dictionary has 2 keys with 2 values. 1 Key = (_*NSCFString) "games" (value: (*_NSCFArray*)) and the other one is "id"(of the player). 
Because I want the recent games I do `[json objectForKey:@"games"]`. Now I get a `NSArray` with 10 objects. The first object is listed below. 
How can I say to my Label which champion (from championID) the player played or which game type he played? Because this is all in 1 object.

How can i split the array to get all the information?

I appreciate every help. 
Thank you for your time.

```
'NSLogged' [ objectAtIndex:0]

{
championId = 102;
createDate = 1394092919791;
fellowPlayers =     (
            {
        championId = 37;
        summonerId = 23497430;
        teamId = 200;
    },
            {
        championId = 81;
        summonerId = 29757887;
        teamId = 200;
    },
            {
        championId = 75;
        summonerId = 37419112;
        teamId = 100;
    },
            {
        championId = 64;
        summonerId = 22985242;
        teamId = 100;
    },
            {
        championId = 412;
        summonerId = 50506867;
        teamId = 100;
    },
            {
        championId = 77;
        summonerId = 30770067;
        teamId = 200;
    },
            {
        championId = 61;
        summonerId = 38231891;
        teamId = 200;
    },
            {
        championId = 110;
        summonerId = 46318423;
        teamId = 100;
    },
            {
        championId = 238;
        summonerId = 51117008;
        teamId = 100;
    }
);
gameId = 1359691076;
gameMode = CLASSIC;
gameType = "MATCHED_GAME";
invalid = 0;
level = 30;
mapId = 1;
spell1 = 4;
spell2 = 14;
stats =     {
    assists = 3;
    championsKilled = 4;
    goldEarned = 12280;
    goldSpent = 11945;
    item0 = 1055;
    item1 = 3153;
    item2 = 3075;
    item3 = 3143;
    item4 = 3047;
    item5 = 1011;
    item6 = 3340;
    killingSprees = 2;
    largestKillingSpree = 2;
    largestMultiKill = 1;
    level = 17;
    magicDamageDealtPlayer = 68999;
    magicDamageDealtToChampions = 5146;
    magicDamageTaken = 2044;
    minionsKilled = 226;
    neutralMinionsKilled = 13;
    neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle = 12;
    neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle = 1;
    numDeaths = 1;
    physicalDamageDealtPlayer = 71900;
    physicalDamageDealtToChampions = 2948;
    physicalDamageTaken = 19358;
    team = 200;
    timePlayed = 1814;
    totalDamageDealt = 141513;
    totalDamageDealtToChampions = 8708;
    totalDamageTaken = 21469;
    totalHeal = 3243;
    totalTimeCrowdControlDealt = 276;
    totalUnitsHealed = 1;
    trueDamageDealtPlayer = 614;
    trueDamageDealtToChampions = 614;
    trueDamageTaken = 66;
    turretsKilled = 4;
    wardPlaced = 8;
    win = 1;
};
subType = "CAP_5x5";
teamId = 200; }
```

Update 1:
self.getRecentGames returns a NSDictionary (and it is NOT the getter from self.recentGames)

```
    self.recentGames = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.getRecentGames];
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.recentGames objectForKey:@"games"];
    //now I my dict have 10 object but dict is from type: __NSCFArray
```

Update 2: FINISHED! 
Thanks you very much for your time. After I checked which class the object from the array have it show, that it is a NSDictionary. 
Just so easy and I just could find it out. 
Your answers helped very much!

Comment: Each of your array objects is an `NSDictionary`, right? You should be able to access data inside using things like this: `[((NSDictionary *)[games objectAtIndex:0]) valueForKey:@"championId"];`

Comment: Do you have an array of labels? It isn't clear exactly what you're struggling with - a list of details, of simply getting an item from a dictionary...

Comment: Read the dump.  `{}` surrounds a dictionary, `()` surrounds an array.  Peel one layer at a time.  If need be, write a loop to search your array.  (Yes, there are fancier ways to do the search in one statement, but you'll understand what you're doing better if you write the loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the structure you show in your question, you could do the following:

```
NSDictionary *game = [games objectAtIndex:0]; // That you did already
NSNumber *championID = [game objectForKey:@"championId"];
```

**Edit based on your comment:**

Like user Hot Licks mentioned, if you get such an exception, you are probably assuming you have a dictionary but instead end up with an array. In this case, you'd do the same twice:

```
NSArray *game = [games objectAtIndex:0]; // That you did already
NSNumber *championID = [game objectAtIndex:indexOfChampionId];
```

Although I doubt if the latter is what you are really looking for. So, probably you'll have to check the part where you import your data.

Comment: At the top is a NSDictionary called dict. In this dict are 2 keys the key "games" which represents a NSArray (with the 10 recent games) and the other key is not relevant.So when i do this `NSDictionary *game = [games objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *championID = [game objectForKey:@"championId"];` i will get an error : `-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab6c8e0
2014-03-06 13:55:25.612 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab6c8e0'`

Comment: @IntegerGaming - That error is telling you you have an array, not a dictionary.  Go back and look at the dump again and figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which should help you with your problem. Of course this is only simple scheme which should help you to solve your problem.

The main idea of this solation is to create objects recursively. You must add all properties you need to Game and Champion classes.

```
 NSArray *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
                                                options:kNilOptions 
                                                  error:&error];

 NSMutableArray *games = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (NSDictionary *gameDictionary in json) {
   Game *game = [[Game alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:gameDictionary];
   [games addObject:game];
 }

 //games is the table which your game objects




///Game class
@interface Game
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *champions;

   - (id)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end

 @implementation Game
     - (id)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
 {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
      NSArray *champions = dictionary[@"championId"];
      foreach (NSDictionary *championDictionary in champions) {
          Champion *champion = [[Champion alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:championDictionary];
          [array addObject:champion];

      }
      self.champions = array;
   }

   return self;
 }

 @end

/// Champion class
 @interface Champion 
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *championId;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *summonerId;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *teamId;

   - (id)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

 @end

 @implementation Champion

   - (id)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
   {
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
       self.championId = dictionary[@"championId"];
       self.teamId = dictionary[@"teamId"];
       self.summonerId = dictionary[@"summonerId"]l
     }

     return self;
   }
 @end
```